# Errors when counting data points in polygon

Tags: qgis, shapefile, count

I am trying to count my datapoints inside different polygons, but it gives an error about my shapefile saying:

```
No spatial index exists for points layer, performance will be severely degraded
Feature (131) from “Geology Shapefile” has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the “Ignore invalid input features” option.
Execution failed after 0.95 seconds
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this error?

Comment: Well, the error message says it quite clearly: `Please fix the geometry` (= solution by @Mayo) or `change the Processing setting to the “Ignore invalid input features” option.`

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3):

First try to fix the geometries (Polygon layer) with the [Fix geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#fix-geometries) tool and then run the [Check validity](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#fix-geometries) to check if there are still invalid geometries, if there are try to manually fix them.

Comment: Thank you! This worked

Comment: Thema please accept the answer by hitting the checkbox next to it.

Comment: Hi @user207306, did my answer solved your problem? If it worked mark the answer as accepted, this help people with the same problem to find this answer easy. 